# How can a JComponent notified about the closed event of it's parent J(Internal)Frame?

Tags: java, swing, components, listeners

I want to write a component that monitors other activities, but it's listeners are to be removed when the component's window is closed.

I don't want to write this removal code many times, but want the component to handle it itself. (How) can i do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "write this removal code many times", and "component to handle itself"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JFrame` class (which is the window) has a `processWindowEvent` callback
that takes a single parameter called `Windowevent`

Register this callback and if the parameter is
of `WINDOW_CLOSED` you can call the removal code inside.

In the end the removal code is only written once (as you want it).

See the [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) for more details.

**Update:** See also [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Comment: How can i put this listener, when i'm writing a component? I dont't have reference to the JFrame, only to the parent component.

Comment: You pass the JFrame reference of your application in the construction of your custom component and store it in a private variable inside the class of your component.

Comment: okay, maybe that's the way it should be done. i just hoped we have a way obtaining the jframe or something

Answer (score 1):

I would write something like that

```
class ListenToWindow
extends WindowAdapter
{
MyInternalFrame frame;

public void windowClosed(event)
   {
   this.frame.removeAllTheRequiredListeners();
   }
}

(...)
JFrame window;
MyInternalFrame frame;
(...)
window.addWindowLister(new ListenToWindow(frame));
(...)
```